# Why <img>'s are not stretched when sized with left / right / top / bottom vs width / height

Tags: html, css, image, css-position, stretch

I'd like to understand why `<img>` behaves differently to the rest of block elements when size is defined implicitly (via top/left/bottom/right) instead of (top/left/width/height).

An `<IMG>` is better than a thousand words, so please take a look at the snapshot below:

[image: graphical explanation]

Also I'd like to know if I can force the behaviour of the explicit size using implicit size via additional CSS.

The CSS

```
.container {overflow:hidden; position:relative; width:200px; height:200px; display:inline-block; }
#implicitsize { position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; }
#explicitsize  { position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; }
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="container"><img id="explicitsize" src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3293/3129420363_ea8515d81a.jpg"></div>
<div class="container"><img id="implicitsize" src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3293/3129420363_ea8515d81a.jpg"></div>
```

PD- Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/uzsbnex8/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `<img>` is a [*replaced element*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#replaced-element).

For *absolutely positioned replaced elements*, if the values of `top`/`bottom` are over-constrained, once you set a value for `top`, `bottom` would be ignored. This is true for `left`/`right` properties as well.

> **[10.3 Calculating widths and margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins)** / **[10.3.8 Absolutely positioned, replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-replaced-width)**
>
> 6. If at this point the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for either 'left' (in case the 'direction' property of the containing
>      block is 'rtl') or 'right' (in case 'direction' is 'ltr') and solve
>      for that value.

> **[10.6 Calculating heights and margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins)** / **[10.6.5 Absolutely positioned, replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-replaced-height)**
>
> 6. If at this point the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for
>      'bottom' and solve for that value.

Therefore in this case the absolutely positioned `<img>` element would be position with the respect to `top` and `left` offsets and it will NOT be stretched by `top`, `bottom`, `right` and `left` properties.

Comment: That explains the difference in behaviour vs a <div>. I didn't know about replaced elements, that's why I was puzzled.

Answer (score 2):

It is because with `width` and `height` you are setting the dimension of the image and with the `top,left,bottom,right` you are setting the position and is not affecting the dimension.

Comment: So if I set width & height to "inherit" , it behaves as the first case. What size is "inheriting"? Will this then always work?

Comment: If you inherit the width and the height, the image will take the width and the height of the container. In this case 200px, 200px. It is exactly like having width and height: 100%;